# C++ size_t and double type calculation

Tags: visual-c++, unsigned, size-t

I am not familiar with C++ and current face a problem about size_t calculation with double type. 
I provide a part of source code as below. The variable "storage" is define as double and "pos" as size_t type. How come they can be calculate together? I review the value of "pos and it shows value like 0, 1, 2 and so on. Moreover, in the case of double* result = storage + pos, it shows 108 + 2 comes out the result x 117.

Further, sometimes 108 + 0 comes out the result x zero. what the condition lead to the result?

How do I know the exact value of size_t before the calculation?

Any advice & suggestion is appreciated.

```
    double* getPosValue(size_t pos, IdentifierType *idRule, unsigned int *errorNumber, bool *found)
{

    double * storage = *from other function with value 108*

    double* result = storage + pos;
    uint16_t* stat = status + pos;   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of a variable (or type) can be obtained with:

```
sizeof(variableNameOrTypeName)
```

If you're after the *address* of a given array element such as `variableName[42]`, it's simply:

```
&(variableName[42])
```

with no explicit mucking about with pointers.

If you want to manipulate the actual double *value* when you only have a pointer to it, you need to dereference the pointer. For example:

```
double xyzzy = 108.0;     // this is the VALUE.
double *pXyzzy = &xyzzy;  // this is a POINTER to it.

double plugh = *pXyzzy + 12.0;
```

The final line above gets the *value* from the pointer (`*pXyzzy`) and adds twelve to that, before storing it into another variable named `plugh`.

---

You should be very wary of things like:

```
double * storage = 108;
```

That creates a *pointer* to a double with the address of `108`. In no way does it create an actual double with the value 108. Dereferencing that pointer is likely to lead to, shall we say, *interesting* results :-)

Comment: yes, these is not way to create double * storage = 108; the value of storage was give by another function. sorry for the typo (the value returns from the function is 108.000000).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. int i = sizeof(pos) return 4, but it is not the data value I prefer to. I wanna know the value inside the size_t for math calculation like 108+12 = 120 and so on. it returns 108+4 = 117 or 108+2 = 0.  Could you help me... Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the properly reply. one more question, how do I convert size_t to pointer like double *pos? Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Dean, I'm not sure that even makes sense. A pointer is an address of something, a _location._ `size_t` is a _size._ They're two different things, it's like asking how to turn a property size (400 m^2) into its street address (42 Smith Street).

Comment: Hi Paxdiable, thanks for u expanation. i understand ur description of size_t and pointers now. C++ is new for me. one more question, what dose mean storage + pos? they are different type, but some calculatio inside the formula when plus tHem togrther? how do i know the result via sample mathmatics while i am debuging the calculation "double* result = storage + pos"? i can see the value of storage, but can not know the value of pos.